# Validation rule for deletion of files or check via flow

Tags: visual-workflow, validation-rule, files, fileupload

We have files with special categories, if a new file is uploaded the category is mandatory for each file.
Category A - can deleted
Category B - cant deleted

I though I can make a validation rule like "Text(category__c) == "B". But if I upload a new file with category B I get my error which I have added for the validation rule.

Second idea was to add a flow to validate the deletion, but I can't choose the file object for run the flow if record is deleted.

Comment: as suggested by @davidCheng below both suggested options by you are not feasible. Easiest to write a trigger event. However, it may not a bad idea to evaluate if such a need arises for the other type of file; in the future, the solution you would build for this should be configurable enough to add more filters/ rules for such use cases; only if adding value, not just one field. #foodForThought

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to write an Apex trigger to prevent deletion of ContentDocument (file) records.  Validation rules cannot prevent record deletion, and you currently cannot use Flow on the ContentDocument object.